# Control autocompletion

Tags: sublimetext4

SublimeText 4 has some more autocompletion functions, which is very nice. However, I am seeking to control these features. In particular, in a C++ code, when I type

```
/**
```

and press <kbd>enter</kbd>
I get

```
/**
 *
```

But I'm looking to either:

- remove the inserted `*`, or
- change the default indentation.

Just to clarify the latter, by default the alignment is as follows:

```
/**
 * This is my docstring.
```

but I want the first character to respect my default indentation of 4 to get

```
/**
 *  This is my docstring.
```

At the moment I'm not even sure which term goes along with this functionality.